# Python v2.7. PyGame. Difference in pixels size between image.load and image.fill

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, pygame, size

I'm trying make a simple game on Python v2.7 (something like a danmaku shooter)

I've got problem with this part

```
import os
from pygame import *

MOVE_SPEED = 3
WIDTH = 10
HEIGHT = 10
COLOR = "#F52525"

class Player(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.startX = x
        self.startY = y
        self.image = Surface((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
        #self.image.fill(Color(COLOR))
        self.image = image.load("images/player.png")
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
```

"player.png" size is 40x60, but I need in actual size 10x10 rectangle at the center of image which will interact with the game logic (with option to display over or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*So I think you want to scale the image down?*
 -- no

**edit**

you will need to offset the drawing and the collision `rect`

```
--------   (x,y)          drawing
|\     | 
| \--  |     (x+15,y+25)  rect
|  --  |       (10,10)
|      | 
--------         (40,60)
```

so basically you want the the collisions to happen inside the image. 
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect

```
def interact(something, player):
   # note both Sprites must have a rect attributes
   return pygame.sprite.collide_rect(something,player)
```

Comment: Thank you for comment. No, it's just reduces image to 10x10. I want get something like that http://en.touhouwiki.net/images/a/a0/Th11Hitbox.png
I think I'll try to use a sprite instead of a single image maybe...

Comment: So you need to crop 10X10 of the 40x60 image?

Comment: No. I need to display a picture on top of the rectangle, which will be in the center of the image, for example. So we will get a picture 40x60, which is just a visual effect and 10x10 rectangle inside it. If you will collide the picture with block - all fine, but if the rectangle with block - you lose. Picture for player, rectangle for game logic and programming.

Answer (score 0):

You might know that each sprite consist of an **`image`** (which is drawn on a surface) and a **`rect` object** (sets location of the `image` and area for collision detection).

You could create a **new** `rect` object in your `player` class …

```
self.collideRect =  pygame.rect.Rect((0, 0), (10, 10))
```

… and set its location to

```
self.collideRect.center = self.rect.center
```

Every time you change the position of your `player` you must call this line too, so your `self.collideRect` rect object *"moves"* with your `player` on screen.

To test if a point (e.g. the mouse coordinates) is inside the `self.collideRect`, call

```
if self.collideRect.collidepoint(x, y) == True:
    print("You clicked on me!")
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use rect argument in blit:

```
screen.blit(image, dest, (x_crop, y_crop, width, height))
```

If you would want to use center you should define image function `blit(screen, dest)`:

```
screen.blit(self.image, dest, self.rect)
```

Comment: the title of his question is misleading. he wants to draw the entire image in the 40x60 but only do collisions on the center 10x10.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry because I misleaded title. I have no idea how to do only collision on the center (I don't use `pygame.sprites`). Should I delete the answer?

Comment: I think @elegent has a good answer, I always take these questions as a learning exercise. the `pygame.sprites` have a `rect` for collision and a `image` for drawing. Your answer does work thought for clipping the image in the space. I originally mentioned to scale the image, which is why i edited my answer.